# View resulting alias command

Tags: mercurial

Let's say I have this alias defined in mercurial config:

```
pushb = push -B `cat .hg/bookmarks.current`
```

How can I view what command will be called after all substitutions apllied?

Example:

My `.hg/bookmarks.current` file contains `some_bookmark` text. How can I view that when I call `hg pushb` it'll actually call `hg push -B some_bookmark`?

Answer (score 0):

When you use `-B <bookmark>` in push and this local bookmark exist, you can see

```
pushing to ...
searching for changes
...
exporting bookmark <bookmark>
```

in push output in case of correct expansion or

```
bookmark <bookmark> does not exist on the local or remote repository!
```

in latest string in case of problem and getting bad name. Anyway, your can see resulted bookmark's name in both cases

Comment: Thanks, but pushing bookmark was just an example. I want this feature for any alias.